# Eclipse Maven project ClassNotFoundException at run time

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, geotools

I would like to try CRS transformations with GeoTools. I created a new Maven project in Eclipse and set the dependencies. The `pom.xml` file contains the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>geotools-homolosine</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>21-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
          <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
          <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
          <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
          <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
          <artifactId>gt-epsg-extension</artifactId>
          <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>boundless</id>
          <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

The Maven commands to *clean* and *install* both complete successfully and the libraries downloaded are shown by Eclipse within the *Maven Dependencies* folder.

I then created a simple programme:

```
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;

public class Transformation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CoordinateReferenceSystem WORLDCRS = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs;
        MathTransform transform = null;

        try 
        {
            crs = CRS.decode("3035");
            transform = CRS.findMathTransform(WORLDCRS, crs, true);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(transform.toWKT());
        System.out.println(transform.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

The Java editor reports no errors or warnings. However, when I run the programme (*Right click* > *Run as* > *Java Application*), the Console shows the following:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/referencing/crs/CoordinateReferenceSystem
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Somehow the Maven dependencies are not reachable at run time. What could be amiss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by the absence of a `build` section in the `pom.xml` file. Among other things, this section identifies the main class of the project. Apparently, Eclipse is not able to lauch the project correctly without this information. Here is the `build` section matching the project described above:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <phase>test</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>java</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
      <mainClass>org.ldesousa.Transformation</mainClass>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that I had to include the main into a package (`org.ldesousa` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I created a test maven project using your code and then imported it into eclipse and everything works fine, once you change `3035` to `EPSG:3035`.

I would check that you are not in off-line mode when you do a maven project refresh to make sure the jars are downloaded.

Comment: The libraries are being downloaded correctly into the `.m2` folder, I suspect this is an issue with Eclipse itself (or the way I am using it). You say that you created the project outside Eclipse and then imported it, while I created everything within Eclipse. How exactly did you create the project?

Comment: I used mvn -B archetype:generate \                                           
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.ianturton -DartifactId=transform

Comment: I created the project outside Eclipse directly with Maven, as you suggest. Then imported it to Eclipse and tried to run: same error as before.